# How to install react-table into Electron (with React) project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, create-react-app, react-table

I created Electron simple project using `create-react-app`. I'd like to use `react-table` component but I have a problem importing its css. Before that I added `react-bootstrap` to the project.

There's really not much code beside:

`npx create-react-app my-app` - Created project

`npm install react-bootstrap` - Added bootstrap

`npm install react-table` - Installed react-table

I added this to the App component:

```
import { useTable, useSortBy } from "react-table";
import "react-table/react-table.css";
```

... and I'm getting this error in the browser:

> ./src/components/App/App.jsx Module not found: Can't resolve
>   'react-table/react-table.css' in
>   '/Users/foo/Projects/test-project/src/components/App'

It's just a `css` file, that I'm having problem with. `import { useTable, useSortBy } from "react-table";` works good alone.

Am I missing something? This is the way I usually install npm libraries.

Comment: Any progress on the issue?